# Is this configuration for email is secure?

Tags: ssl, smtp, email-server, node.js

I am using `nodemailer` package with `node.js` to sending mails, and I am not sure about security.
The host I've received is working only with this configuration (also with port 587):

```
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'some.host.address.org',
    port: 25,
    requireTLS: false,
    secure: false,
  })
```

For this configuration:

```
requireTLS: true,
secure: false,
```

I am getting error:
`Error upgrading connection with STARTTLS: 500 5.3.3 Unrecognized command`

For this configuration:

```
port: 465,
secure: true,
```

I have another error
`error: 4605283776:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:`

So my assumptions are my host is not supporting STARTTLS nor TLS.
But when I am checking these mails in client, I can see in message headers this information:

```
Received: from mycompany.domain (mycompany.domain.com. [*some IP address*])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id sxxxxxxxios.xx.2020.04.20.xx.xx.xx
        for `<id@some.host.address.org>`
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
        Mon, 20 Apr 2020 09:26:18 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain some.host.address.org configured xxx.xxx.xx.xxx as internal address)
```

So I am not sure if my mails are sent with encryption or not, if this nodemailer conifugration is secure, and how it is possible that I can see TLS in message header, possible that I do not understand sth here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail deliver is done by the SMTP protocol. This is a  hop-by-hop protocol which means that connections are at most encrypted between the hops (i.e. mail servers) and that each mail server in between can read (and change) the mail. What you see in the specific Received header are information about the connection from your companies mail server to Google's mail server, which looks encrypted. But in your code you configure the connection between your client and the local mail server, which might not support encryption.